# How to sort an array(in ascending order) based on the ranks of each element which is in the another array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, comparison

Let two arrays

```
arr = [1,5,6,3,10] 


rank = [100,0,1,100,2]
```

Based on the `rank` array (Which holds the `ranks` of the mirror elements in the `arr`) the result should be

```
[5,6,10,1,3]
```

The first element in the result is `5`

> (The index of 5 in arr is `arr[1]` and the index of `0` in rank is
> `rank[1]`. This is how we have to take ranks.  0 is smallest of all ranks so 5 is printed first )

The second element in the result is `6`

> The index of `6` in `arr` array is at the index `arr[2]` and its rank is
> `1` because that is at the index `rank[2]`. 1 is the second smallest
> of all ranks so 6 is printed next)
> This is how we have to sort the array based on the rank array.
>
> ```
> Here if two ranks are same then we have to compare the values in the array itself and print the smaller first
> arr[0] = 1 and arr[3] = 3 Both having same ranks 100. So compare those elements and print the smallest value. That gives the
> ```
>
> result
> `5,6,10,1,3`

Comment: Can you alter `rank` or create additional datastructures? It's a lot easier if you can just create an array of pairs, sort that, and then extract the desired values.

Comment: Yes we can. Can you solve this with C++ ? .I have solved that with unordered_map and messed up with some logic. Can you please come up with solving the following test case too?

Comment: second test case : arr = [3,1,2,5] , rank = [1,1,2,2] => result = [1,3,2,5] .Hope you get this one. arr elements 1 and 3 have rank 1, so they are compared and 1 is written in result[0] and 3 is written in result[1]. similarly for last 2 elements

Comment: Well, the point of **un**ordered_map is that it's not ordered (sorted). You're almost there, just use a `std::map`.

Comment: Used that too. 1st test case was successful, but the second one failed miserably.

Comment: Then show that code! Including the expected and actual outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: `std::sort`.

The long answer depends on how you store the values and the ranks, whether you can afford to copy them, and whether you also need the ranks sorted. For the following I assumed that you do not need the ranks sorted and the sorting is done on the original container of values. It is not the most efficient implementation, but it is simple enough to get you started:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Iter,typename RankIter>
void rank_sort(Iter begin,Iter end,RankIter rankbegin){
    std::vector<std::pair<typename std::iterator_traits<RankIter>::value_type,
                          typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type >> res;
    for (auto beg = begin; beg != end; ++beg,++rankbegin) res.emplace_back(*rankbegin,*beg); 
    std::sort(res.begin(),res.end());
    for (const auto& e : res){
        *begin = e.second;
        ++begin;
    }
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr{1,5,6,3,10};
    std::vector<int> rank{100,0,1,100,2};
    rank_sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),rank.begin());
    for (const auto& a : arr) { std::cout << a << " ";}
}
```

The basic idea is to create a `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` and then simply sort that via `std::sort`. The rest of the code is about copying the values and ranks into that vector and copying the values out of it after sorting.

If possible you should store the values and ranks in a `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` in the first place. Then sorting them is trivial. Alternatively, as mentioned in a comment, you can use a sorted container, like eg a `std::map`.

Comment: That was great. Thank you. I have a small request. Can you solve this without STL? That will be help me a lot.

Comment: @DoubleH I suppose you mean the standard library (STL is the standard template library which was the predecessor of many parts of the standard library). Why? I think I could write a replacement for `std::sort` but I never did and honestly I don't feel like. You can search for sorting algorithms on the web.

Comment: @DoubleH: The STandard Library is an integral part of C++. Of course it is possible, some companies use alternative libraries. I believe Electronic Arts uses EASTL instead. But every sane programmer uses libraries for this sort of thing(s).

Comment: `std::pair<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type,
                          typename std::iterator_traits<RankIter>::value_type >` seem wrong sequence here, the rankiter should be first

Comment: No , I just meant without using the vector / map / similar stuff, can you solve this problem directly with arrays?

Comment: @DoubleH `std::sort` also works with plain arrays. You could write a `struct value_and_rank { int value; int rank; };` use an array of that struct and sort that.

Comment: @DoubleH when you have such requirements (and not using standard containers is a rather drastic one) you should mention them in the quesiton.

Comment: Just guess this is a homework that should not STL :)

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I was writing C++ the way I was thaught in school for years and it was a world of pain. Took me quite some effort to realize how much fun it can be if one just uses it right. Teaching C++ without the standard library is doing more harm than good.

Comment: Totally agree!!

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin that was a coding round question for me in a company's placement process.